# How do I let touch events propagate to TouchableOpacity wrapped text links?

Tags: react-native

I have some text with `onPress` wrapped in a `TouchableOpacity`.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={doNavigateToComment}>
  <View>
    <Text>
      <Text onPress={doNavigateToUser}>
        @{user.username}
      </Text>{" "}
      liked your comment.
    </Text>
  </View>
   ... more stuff ...
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Tapping anywhere on that text will trigger `doNavigateToComment`. When the user taps the username it should call `doNavigateToUser` Is there a way to give the underlying `Text` `onPress` priority? It seems to only recognize the outer touchable wrapper.

Comment: can you try changing onpress functions to this.doNavigateToComment and this.doNavigateToUser ?

Comment: The functions are local to the render() function, so not using `this` is appropriate here. I've tested that both functions do work, just not as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code a little bit, but I am getting exactly your intended behavior.

```
doNavigateToComment() {
    console.log('doNavigateComment');
  }
  doNavigateToUser() {
    console.log('doNavigateToUser');
  }
   <View style={styles.container}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => this.doNavigateToComment()}>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 40, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }} >
        <Text>
          <Text
            style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }}
            onPress={() => this.doNavigateToUser()}>
            Username
          </Text>{' '}
          liked your comment.
        </Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
```

Pressing on Username (blue area) will print `doNavigateToUser` and pressing the red area will print `doNavigateComment`. 
You probably just need to adapt your styling.

Screenshot:

[image: Example]

Working expo:

https://snack.expo.io/SkOzaxdiV

Comment: Your sample app works but my app still has the wrong behavior. The text link won't trigger, it always favors the wrapping TouchableOpacity. One difference is that my app is vanilla React Native, not Expo, and I wonder if there is some kind of implementation difference there? My implementation is also the renderItem of a FlatList, but breaking it out to a standalone View did not help either.

Comment: You should probably add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: Yup, I created a new app with `react-native init` and dropped in your code with slight mods to remove expo. Worked perfectly. Thank you for putting that together. The problem is somewhere else in my app. This component acts as the renderItem for a `ListView`, which is rendered inside of several nested React Navigation stacks. If I remove the `TouchableOpacity`, the username link works. Can you think of anything that would cause a `TouchableOpacity` to take priority like that? Anything that would control tap propagation? I'm not using `PointerEvents`, so really at a loss here.

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe you can get it to work with applying a `zIndex`, but that's just guessing. 
If my answer helped you, I would appreciate an upvote and/or an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I was importing `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native-gesture-handler` instead of `react-native`. Once I fixed that import the taps started working correctly.